# Recently i have dowloaded Ubuntu 23.04 . but im my system(ASUS LAPTOP ) wireless wifi is not working it shows (NO WIFI ADAPTER FOUND). How to fix it

Tags: networking, wireless, 23.04, adapter

This image shows that there is no Wifi adapter found. Basically, when I am trying to connect my ASUS laptop to wireless Wifi then it shows no Wifi adapter is found. Last time when I am installed Ubuntu 22.04 then the same issues occurs. Now I have installed a new version of Ubuntu 23.04, but my issue is same as previous.

How to fix it?
Does anyone have an idea how to solve this issue?

When I am running this command

```
sudo apt install rtl8821ce-dkms
```

my terminal shows

> [E: Unable to locate package rtl8821ce-dkms]

How to fix this issue?

From our Community [chili555] suggested me to
Run this (lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3) command
but when i am running this commmand then nothing  showing anything in my terminal.just simply accept my code.

Comment: How did you fix it before?

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal command: `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.